# How to Hide/Show Elements Using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using 'Show More' and 'Show Less' pagination  [Please see this for live](http://projects.santabantathegreat.com/glassicam/design2/dashboard.html)

I want to hide or show 'Show Less' and 'Show More' depending on the number of boxes.  If the values is greater than 3 we should show 'Show Less' and if the value is less than 4 we should show 'Show More'

Here's my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var size_li = $(".carousel-row").size();
    var x=3;            

    $('.carousel-row:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('.carousel-row:lt('+x+')').show();                
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('.carousel-row').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();                        
    });
});

</script>
```

Then I want to hide this elements:

```
<div id="loadMore" class="loadMore">Load More</div>
        <div id="showLess" class="showLess">Show Less</div>

can you do for this  <div class="row carousel-row lss">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 slide-row">
            <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide slide-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators lsse">
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150?rand=1" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150?rand=2" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150?rand=3" alt="Image">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-content">
                <h4>Example product</h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
                    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-footer">
                <span class="pull-right buttons">
                      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" onclick="relocateTo('jobtitle.html')"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>View Job</button>

                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the two `divs` you listed you should use this jQuery call:

```
$('#loadMore').hide()
$('#showLess').hide()
```

In order to do that with the logic you provided you should use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var size_li = $(".carousel-row").size();
    var x=3;            

    $('.carousel-row:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('.carousel-row:lt('+x+')').show();                
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('.carousel-row').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();                        
    });



  $('#showLess, #loadMore').click(function () {
    if($(".carousel-row:visible").size() > 3){
        $('#loadMore').hide();
        $('#showLess').show(); 
    }else{
        $('#showLess').hide();
        $('#loadMore').show();              
    }                       
 });
});
```

**For more information on jQuery.hide() check this link: http://api.jquery.com/hide/**

Comment: but if the boxes are four it not showing both links

Comment: it's not working  my question is to hide show less and show more if the boxes are 3 if more i want to get that

Comment: @user3396954 I just confirmed and you didnt update the script =( can you please check again?

Comment: I changed the answer, make sure you have this line ` $('#showLess, #loadMore').click(function () { `

Comment: Hello, i updated one last time the answer, i hope thats what you want =)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to show/hide elements, jQuery `.toggle()` is quite helpful. Also, if you're looking to select a certain number of like elements (by index), `.slice()` can come in very handy.

- [slice() docs](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)
- [toggle() docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

**Example:**

**[Update - Based on OP edit:]**

```js
/// Setup:
// Get all .carousel-row elements more than 3
var rowsMoreThanThree = $('.carousel-row').slice(3),
    rows = $('.carousel-row'),
    loadMore = $('#loadMore'),
    showLess = $('#showLess');

// show or hide more and less buttons based on number of boxes:
if (rows.length > 3) {
  loadMore.hide();
} else{
  showLess.hide();
}


// Toggle!
$('.toggler').click(function(){
    rowsMoreThanThree.toggle('slow');
    $('.toggler').toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
div {
    padding: 20px;
    border: dashed 2px steelblue;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.searchContainer, #globalSearchInput {
    background-color: pink;
}
.black{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel-row">Row 1</div>
<div class="carousel-row">Row 2</div>
<div class="carousel-row">Row 3</div>
<div class="carousel-row">Row 4</div>
<div class="carousel-row">Row 5</div>
<div class="carousel-row">Row 6</div>

<button class="toggler" id="loadMore">Load More</button>
<button class="toggler" id="showLess">Show Less</button>
```

Comment: updated questions  please check i want for that code

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand *exactly* what you need based on your description. I'm almost certain that you can use the answer I posted to achieve what you are looking for (with some minor tweaking.) Please clarify.